# How to get the offset position for each element of class name?

Tags: javascript, html, class, position, offset

How can I get the top offset position for each element using **classname**?

I need to return a value for each class named `.Me`

*(**Can't** use jQuery this time)*

This is how I am trying to do it:

```js
var list = document.querySelectorAll('.Me');

for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    var me = document.getElementsByClassName('Me');
    console.log(me.offsetTop);
}
```

```css
div,p { position: relative; }
div{ background:#ddd;}
.Me{ background:#7ae;}
```

```html
<p>Content before container</p>
<div>
    <p>Space</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>padding</p>
    <p class="Me">Me 1</p>
    <p class="Me">Me 2</p>
    <p class="Me">Me 3</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to select each element of your list by doing `list[index]` like so:

```js
var list = document.getElementsByClassName('Me');

for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    var me = list[i];
    console.log(me.offsetTop);
}
```

```css
div,p { position: relative; }
div{ background:#ddd;}
.Me{ background:#7ae;}
```

```html
<p>Content before container</p>
<div>
    <p>Space</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>padding</p>
    <p class="Me">Me 1</p>
    <p class="Me">Me 2</p>
    <p class="Me">Me 3</p>
</div>
```